# Generate list of all chrome tabs across android devices?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, android, browser-tabs, tabs

I know [chrome://history/syncedTabs](http://chrome://history/syncedTabs) will show me *recent* chrome tabs, but I want to be able to see *all* chrome tabs.  I have 4 or 5 devices, each of which has 100+ tabs.

I don't need to retain any state from any of these tabs -- I just want to get the URLs.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I suspect there's a temp user file on each device which lists the open tabs.  Finding that would give me what I need.

Comment: This answer seems to list the location.  I'll need to check up on this and report back!  https://android.stackexchange.com/a/116876

Comment: ^ `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you aren't rooted, my comments above are a no-go.

However, you can accomplish the same thing by using [chrome devtools' remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/).

Start by plugging your android device into your computer and firing up chrome.  Then, in the chrome dev tools, click the hamburger button --> More tools --> Remote Devices.

[image]

As long as you've enabled USB Debugging on your android device, you should be able to select your phone from the list of devices.  This displays all of the tabs you have open!

[image]

From there, you can select-all and copy to get your tab URLs.

**Note: if a tab has a "long" URL, it will be shortened with an `…` in the middle of the URL.  If you specifically need URLs that have been shortened like this, be sure to right-click the link and copy the full URL!**

Comment: "Remote devices" option is not there anymore - unless maybe there is some trick to enable it?

Comment: @TomWarfield You are correct, that seems to have been removed.  Arg.  I'm faced with this issue again, myself, with additional browsers on Android.  I'm tempted to hack something together using [Appium](https://appium.io/docs/en/latest/) to scrape the URLs for each tab.